# Is there a way to delete a message with Microsoft-Graph C# client library?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph client in my C#.net project and I notice that Message item doesn't expose any method for Deleting message.

I tried

```
client.Me.Messages[mail.Id].Delete()
```

And I see that Delete method isn't present.

What shall I do?

Comment: client.Me.Messages[mail.Id].DeleteAsync() should work. All rest method in Graph Library should be with async.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create the `Request` object that holds the `DeleteAsync()` method:

```
graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .Messages["your message id"]
    .Request()
    .DeleteAsync();
```

Based on your own code:

```
await client
  .Me
  .Messages[mail.Id]
  .Request()
  .DeleteAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this client library but I had a look at [its Github repo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet). It is not very clear from the repo docs how to delete a message, but the docs for MS Graph indicates there is a way to delete a message via its API:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_delete

Based on the client repo though, it looks like you simply need to create a [`MessageRequest`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/f807196101e20d30fbc8628206a2eb5850334a92/src/Microsoft.Graph/Requests/Generated/MessageRequest.cs#L29) and call its `DeleteAsync()` method.

The `MessageRequest` class accepts a request url, which presumably would be the message url (something like `/me/messages/{id}`).

Answer (score -1):

I used this:

```
public static async Task DeleteEmail(string emailId)
        {
            TokenCache tokens = TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache();
            PublicClientApplication clientApp = new PublicClientApplication(secret, RootAuthUri, tokens);

            using (HttpClient c = new HttpClient())
            {
                string requestURI = RootUri + "/me/messages/" + emailId;

                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, requestURI);
                //Authentication token
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await GetTokenAsync(clientApp));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await c.SendAsync(request);
                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

        }


private static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(PublicClientApplication app)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            string[] scopes = { "User.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite" };
            try
            {

                // Get the token from the cache.
                result = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, (await app.GetAccountsAsync()).FirstOrDefault());
                return result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. 
                // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
                Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                try
                {
                    // Dialog opens for user.
                    result = await app.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
                    return result.AccessToken;
                }
                catch (MsalException msalex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}");
                return null;
            }
        }

static class TokenCacheHelper
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the user token cache
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static TokenCache GetUserCache()
        {
            if (usertokenCache == null)
            {
                usertokenCache = new TokenCache();
                usertokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
                usertokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
            }
            return usertokenCache;
        }

        static TokenCache usertokenCache;

        /// <summary>
        /// Path to the token cache
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly string CacheFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".msalcache.bin";

        private static readonly object FileLock = new object();

        public static void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {

            lock (FileLock)
            {
                args.TokenCache.Deserialize(File.Exists(CacheFilePath)
                    ? ProtectedData.Unprotect(File.ReadAllBytes(CacheFilePath),
                                              null,
                                              DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                    : null);
            }
        }

        public static void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
            if (args.TokenCache.HasStateChanged)
            {
                lock (FileLock)
                {
                    // reflect changesgs in the persistent store
                    File.WriteAllBytes(CacheFilePath,
                                       ProtectedData.Protect(args.TokenCache.Serialize(),
                                                             null,
                                                             DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser)
                                      );
                    // once the write operationtakes place restore the HasStateChanged bit to filse
                    args.TokenCache.HasStateChanged = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is Graph Rest API but not Graph library. The Graph Library should work s well too. client.Me.Messages[mail.Id].DeleteAsync(). All rest method in Graph Library should be with async.

Comment: The method that you said, doesn't exist

Comment: need to call the Request method first. I have add my worked code below.